# How to display monthly attendance data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two tables

### TblEmployee

attendance_id  employee_id  Scan_type   Date_and_time
  1              1            IN          15-Jan-19 8:00:00 AM
  2              1            IN          15-Jan-19 8:00:02 AM
  3              2            IN          15-Jan-19 8:05:01 AM
  4              2            OUT         15-Jan-19 4:00:00 PM
  5              1            IN          16-Jan-19 8:05:30 AM

AttendanceTable

emp_id       emp_name
  1            Salman
  2            Tahir
  3            Jameel

I want to display monthly record data of all employees with in and out times. In time will be the first time with "iN" and out time will be the last time with "OUT". Employee may forget to sign-in or sign-out so in that case the field will remain blank or show "absent".

I am trying to do like this but don't know what to do next

```
 var InList = from a in _context.TblEmployee
                         from e in _context.AttendanceTable.Where(x => 
                         a.EmpId == x.EmployeeId)
                         .Where(x => x.ScanType == "IN")
                         .OrderBy (x => x.DateAndTime)
                         .DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new
                       {
                           AttDate = e.DateAndTime.Date,
                           Emp_name = a.EmployeeName,
                           Emp_Id = e.EmployeeId
                       };
var OutList = from a in _context.TblEmployee
                         from e in _context.AttendanceTable.Where(x => 
                         a.EmpId == x.EmployeeId)
                         .Where(x => x.ScanType == "OUT")
                         .OrderBy (x => x.DateAndTime)
                         .DefaultIfEmpty()
                       select new
                       {
                           AttDate = e.DateAndTime.Date,
                           Emp_name = a.EmployeeName,
                           Emp_Id = e.EmployeeId
                       };
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code to the absolute minimum required to understand the question, i.e. a [mcve]. And also indent it property to make it readable.

Comment: You want record of all `employees` for a particular month of record of `one employee` for a particular month?

Comment: in and out times for all employees for a specific month

Comment: Repost your custom ViewModel.

Comment: ViewModel added to my question

Comment: Well, that's not an MCVE. Now all that's left is a vague problem description "but not successful". I think the view code wasn't relevant and most of the comments weren't. But the code throwing the exception obviously was.

Comment: _but not successful_ - more details you provide about _but not successful_ quicker and better answers you will get. Even better you will find solution by yourself and remove the question ;)

Comment: not successful means i am unable to write query or i don't know how to write query for this problem

Comment: I *think* the data model makes it harder than necessary. You probably should have an attendance record having both start time and end time, so you don't have to find matching check-ins and check-outs. You only have to find the last check-in if someone checks out.

Comment: Actually the model is scaffolded from database which is linked with biometric machines. i have to get records from that database and use in my application

Comment: This is my fist question in any forum. May be i haven't explained my problem well. Should i re-describe it?

Comment: Usually it helps to show sample data and sample output, as text in the question (not as images).